# How to change color of quick links

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, quick-links

**What I have:**
I am using SharePoint Online (Office 365). I have a publishing site with team site features enabled.

I have quick links on my main page, set to grid/tiles. Each link/tile consists of an image and a rectangle with name.

**What I want to do:**
I would like to change the color of the rectangle - customize the look of quick links.

**What I've already tired:**

- Changing theme (doesn't change the color of quick links).
- Using custom CSS (it's not an option with the modern experience).
- Changing the color palette (This one still looks promising, but I wasn't able to make it work. Perhaps it's also a problem on the modern experience).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Modern Script web part then use this web part in your main page with custom CSS code to change color of links.

There is a blog about configuring Modern Script Web Part for your reference:
[SharePoint | Online | Best Practice | install Modern Script Editor Web Part for SharePoint Online Modern Site.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d4b8b3c4-8950-4407-9120-204b80fc35f9/sharepoint-online-best-practice-install-modern-script-editor-web-part-for-sharepoint-online?forum=odspproductsandservicesharing)